# Who has a brother who is grand dad?

Tags: prolog

I am trying to query who has a brother that is a grandad but cannot figure it out, I know its simple but its confusing me a little.

I have some basic facts here:

```
parent(queenmother,elisabeth). parent(elisabeth,charles).
parent(elisabeth,andrew). parent(elisabeth,anne).
parent(elisabeth,edward). parent(diana,william).
parent(diana,harry). parent(sarah,beatrice).
parent(anne,peter). parent(anne,zara).
parent(george,elisabeth). parent(philip,charles).
parent(philip,andrew). parent(philip,edward)...
```

I have some predicates that determins male from female:

```
the_royal_males(charles). the_royal_males(andrew).
the_royal_males(edward). the_royal_males(william).
the_royal_males(philip). the_royal_males(phillip).
the_royal_males(georgejun). the_royal_males(harry).
```

and to determin ancestors, brothers, siblings.

```
ancestor(X,Y):- parent(X,Y).
ancestor(X,Y):- parent(X,Z), ancestor(Z,Y).

sibling(X,Y):- parent(Z,X), parent(Z,Y), X \= Y.

brother(X,Y):- sibling(X,Y), sibling(Y,X), the_royal_males(Y), X \= Y.
```

The queries i've been trying such as

```
brother(X,_), ancestor(X,_)
```

Isn't giving the desired results. Any help/guidance would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Your current query `brother(X, _), ancestor(X, _)` is true if `X` is the brother of somebody and `X` is also an ancestor. The query you need should have at least two variables.  The question is, *Who (X) has a brother (Y) who is a grand dad?*. So the `brother` rule would be `brother(X, Y)`. Then you need a call to tell if `Y` is a grand dad. If you had a predicate, `granddad(Y)`, that is true if `Y` is a grand dad, it would just be, `brother(X, Y), granddad(Y)`. You don't necessarily have to implement `granddad` *per se*, but you need it or a sequence of calls equivalent to it.

Comment: In according to your question " Who has a brother who is grand dad ? " I advice you to distinguish granddad from ancestor . If the answer That You aspect is important for your program then create two more rules. That is , grand_dad ( X, Y) and grand_mom ( X, Y) .
Theoretically an ancestor could be a parent , a grandparent , great grandparent and so on . So create rules like grand_dad ( X , Y ) : - male ( X ) , parent ( X , Z ) , parent ( Z , Y ). Similarly for the grand_mom. Finally try your query with: ?:-brother(_, X), grand_dad(X, ).

Comment: Start out by finding better predicate names. Ideally, the names should indicate what the arguments are like.